# No Broker Error for Self hosted schema registry with Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Please find above docker-compose file. I am trying to self host schema registry but receiving below error.

```
    services:
      zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.0
        hostname: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper
        ports:
          - '32181:32181'
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
          ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        extra_hosts:
          - "moby:127.0.0.1"

      kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.0.0
        hostname: kafka
        container_name: kafka
        ports:
          - '9092:9092'
          - '29092:29092'
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
        e

nvironment:
              KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
              KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
              KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
              KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
              KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
              KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
              KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
              KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
              KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
              CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
              CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
              CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
              CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
              CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
            extra_hosts:
              - "moby:127.0.0.1"
    schema-registry:
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.0.0
        hostname: schema-registry
        container_name: schema-registry
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
          - kafka
        ports:
          - '8081:8081'
        environment:
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
          SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:32181
        extra_hosts:
          - "moby:127.0.0.1"

    org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        connect_1                |      at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        connect_1                |      at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
        connect_1                |      at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
        connect_1                |      at io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus.isKafkaReady(ClusterStatus.java:149)
        connect_1                |      at io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand.main(KafkaReadyCommand.java:150)
        connect_1                | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call.
        connect_1                | [main] INFO
```

Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Trying to query Kafka for metadata again 
Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Brokers found

looks like I am missing one of Environment Variables but not sure where to add broker details.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?